# WCF Error "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS ..." out of the blue

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, iis

My WCF service, hosted in IIS for a couple of years now was working fine, but suddenly out of the blue it stopped working when I try to consume it using a Windows app, showing the following error:

```
Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority '***.com'
```

Nothing was changed at all, SSL certificate is fine and when the WCF link opened in browser no certificate warnings appear.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

After almost a day trying to find the cause, it seems that the IT has disabled TLS 1.0 by default in the server (group policy?), this made the client side apps do not work because they were designed with .NET 4.0.

.NET 4.0 does not support TLS 1.1 nor 1.2. Once I updated the client app with .NET 4.5 it worked fine again since it supports both TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

Another option would be enabling TLS 1.0 server side, but I am sure it was switched off for a reason.